# Angular 8 Kendo Grid: Dropdown not showing selected Item in Edit mode

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Here's a gif showing the issue:
[image]
You can see when the 'Edit' button is hit, it enables edit mode. However the dropdown is not displaying the selected value. The dropdown has items, they can be selected, and then the selected item is displayed.

Here's the html structure for the single cell:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="Status" title="Status" width="100">
              <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                {{ statusGrid(dataItem.Status)?.text }}
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate 
                  let-dataItem="dataItem" 
                  let-formGroup="formGroup">
                <kendo-dropdownlist 
                    [data]="statusDropdown"
                    (valueChange)="onStatusChange($event, formGroup)"
                    textField="text"
                    valueField="value"
                    [valuePrimitive]="true"
                    [formControl]="formGroup.get('Status')">
                    <ng-template kendoDropDownListItemTemplate let-dataItem>
                      {{ dataItem.text }}
                    </ng-template>
                </kendo-dropdownlist>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
```

The Javascript behind it was copy/pasted from 
[Online Demo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/custom-reactive-editing/)

Comment: It seems `Inactive` is not among the list of values in you example.

Comment: That was it. If you make an answer out of it, I'll approve it.